# Fresh ASP.NET Core project with build errors?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget

Went thru and created a new project from the Angular template (.NET Core 2.1 list), and the only thing i did was to try to build it. Got 100 Errors.

[image]

My project is of .NET Core 2.1, why am I getting these .NET Core related errors? I've done nothing with the template.

I'm using .NET Core 2.1 (screenshot) with Visual Studio 15.8.0

My installed SDKs

[image]

Comment: Which version of the .NET Core SDK and Visual Studio 2017 are you using?

Comment: Could not reproduce this issue with new project. Please try to clear NuGet cache. Go to VS 2017 -> Tools -> Options -> NuGet Package Manager.  Actioned 'Clear All NuGet Cache(s)', then rebuild the project.

Comment: @KirkLarkin Hello! Im using VS 15.8.0 and Core 2.1 (see screenshot)

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Hi, i cleared the cache (and cleaned solution for good measures) but it did not solve the problem :-(

Comment: @fUrious, Thanks for your reply. This is strange. Could you please share us your test project by onedrive, so that I can build it on my side to check if I can reproduce this issue? It is also help to find out if this issue is related to your project settings or ENV settings.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT Thanks for your response Leo! One thing I've noticed that when running "dotnet --version" I got 2.1.302, the same as my coworker. It was also the same listed in the window when selecting a template upon creating a new project. 
Then I checked the list of programs (see added screenshot) and It states I have even a newer one, 2.1.400. I repaired that one and now my project builds and runs!

Comment: Also please keep in mind, that SDK Version doesn't correspond to .NET Core Runtime version. With .NET Core 2.2 this will change iirc where SDK Version will aliged with the runtime version. i.e. 2.1.200 SDK = .NET Core 2.0, 2.1.400 = .NET Core 2.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing I've noticed that when running "dotnet --version" I got 2.1.302, the same as my coworker. It was also the same listed in the window when selecting a template upon creating a new project. Then I checked the list of programs (see added screenshot) and It states I have even a newer one, 2.1.400. I repaired that one and now my project builds and runs!